# Accessing an OLEDB source through Java

Tags: java, oledb, linked-server, jdbc-odbc

I have a Java app that needs to access a 3rd party database through OLEDB. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I am looking for an answer from the year 2014 on this question - everything I have seen so far is from a few years ago and basically saying this was not possible with an existing solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [EasySoft offers a JDBC-ODBC driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc_odbc_bridge/index.html#section=tab-1), but it isn't free.

Comment: Thanks, one free option I am looking at is creating a linked server - if anyone has any experience with this please comment.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Comment: Ok, I have set up a linked server from SQL Server to the OLEDB source... it was actually very easy. The question now is, does anyone know what the hibernate properties are to connect to a linked server from Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anyone else - I ended up using a Linked Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx